# Astrology signs not displayed by Android's TextView

Tags: android, encoding, textview

I am developing the android version of a website and come into a bizarre problem: the astrology signs are correctly displayed with html by NOT with Android's TextView given that both are using **UTF-8** encoding.

example:

```
myTextView.setText("♈àé中");
```

The text displayed is 'àé中' without the '♈'.

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Weird. I can't see the symbol you have in the ' marks. To me, it is just a box. But I CAN see the symbol in your settext method. Very weird

Comment: There is no guarantee that any stock Android font (e.g., Droid Sans, Roboto) will have all glyphs.

Comment: Use a different ttf font. One that has the required glyphs.

Comment: If you found one of our answers useful, please upvote & accept one.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Roboto font character set here: https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto

You will probably find that those glyphs are missing.

To change the typeface of your TextView to use a font which contains the glyphs you need, use `android:typeface` in layout XML or `setTypeface()` in code.

Answer (score 0):

You could display your wanted symbols by importing them as bitmaps and using [`View.setBackground`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use some different font with all glyphs defined. However, please note that most of such fonts are not royalty free or could not be used in commercial software and having quite serious legal restrictions. Try to find out some free to use fonts here:
https://www.google.com/fonts
However there is also you should pay attention on legal restrictions to use them without any problems.

Hope it would be helpful!